# Grails Resources Order

Tags: grails, resources

I am using the Grails Resources Plugin. Is there a way to define that a resource must be after another ie the Twitter Bootstrap Plugin must be loaded after JQuery UI so that the Tabs work. I need to be able to explictly state that Bootstrap is loaded after JQuery UI I am looking for something like

```
dependsOn 'bootstrap' after:'jquery-ui'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious way to do this would be to specify that the bootstap module `dependsOn` the jquery-ui module. I guess the reason it's not clear how to do this is because both these modules are defined by plugins so you can't modify the module definition directly. Fortunately, it is possible to [override modules defined within plugins](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/5.%20Overriding%20resources.html) without modifying the plugin source code. Simply add something like the following to your `*Resources.groovy`

```
modules = {
    overrides {
        bootstrap {
            dependsOn 'jquery-ui'
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't see it. Not as obvious for me. Thanks